# WCF Upload file

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, upload, stream

I've never used WCF before but I want to create a simple service. I want the computer to upload a file from the local machine. I've got this in my interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",UriTemplate = "/File")]
Stream GetFile();
```

In the method, I just do this:

```
return new FileStream(@"c:\myfile.zip", FileMode.Open);
```

When I run this from the client, the `Result` property contains the stream itself. This is fine, and it works, but I'd rather the client access the file from the server itself instead of copying the entire thing across. What would be the URL for the uploaded file so that the client can access it directly from the server? I assumed it's `http://computername:port/something...` (I believe this is a REST service?)

Comment: If the client is supposed to do something with the file contents then it needs to copy it anyway, no matter how you share it (stream, shared folder, http, ftp, ...), doesn't it?

Comment: But what if a client doesn't consume the WCF service? I assume they can still access the file directly? Also, the above method doesn't allow streaming as it would download the entire file first (e.g. music, video etc..)

Comment: In order to stream a file using WCF you can set the transferMode Property to "Streamed" which would stream your file continuously rather than the Buffered mode which wait until the entire response is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to think over what you are saying.

- A user can access a file directly. In that case it is fair to think, that any user could access any file on any computer. It's obvious, that it's not so.
- WCF provides some special interface to access the files on computer, where it is running. This is also a big security hole.
- any other ideas?

In any case, if you want to share the file on web, you should make a public interface for it.
This could be an IIS server, which will return it from the server machine, or this could be just your WCF server.

Anyway, what you did is right. `Stream` returns a file over network and it has no overhead of copying (duplicating) some information, like you may think.

**UPDATE:**
To enable streaming you can look into this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx)

**UPDATE 2:**
If you really need to stream a video file, [Smooth Streaming](http://www.iis.net/download/SmoothStreaming) could be an option

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting things bit mixed up here. You expose a WCF service with an operation returning a `Stream`. That this is a filestream is an implementation detail. You could just as well return a memory stream or a network stream or anything which derives from `Stream` really. If you want to have the client direct access to the file you need to share it so it can access it. On Windows you could create a shared folder (but you really don't want to expose that on the internet) or you setup a ftp or http server.

I have not tinkered around with WCF and streaming but I would expect that when you supply a stream from the server that it works more or less out of the box (meaning it streams the file rather than downloading it in one big chunk). Have a look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) which details some restrictions around streaming with WCF.

Comment: I tried streaming a video file by directly calling `GetFile` from my client. The client consumes the WCF service, so it can call the method. Calling this method resulted in having to wait until the entire file was downloaded. Once the file finished downloading fully, I was able to access it from the download complete event's `e.Result` property. Until then, I know of no way to access it. I'd rather stream the file, not download the whole thing before playing.  Is this possible with WCF?

Comment: @Skoder: I added the link to MSDN which contains information about streaming over WCF